# Is it possible to have multiple data-{name} atributes in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to get all 3 data values from this element?

```
 <div id="viewport" 
    data-requires='js/base/paths'
    data-requires='js/base/dialog'
    data-requires='js/base/notifier'>
```

This would be really useful for a project that I am starting. With this I could load required js modules and link them to the dom. I know it might sound strange, but I'm trying something new here.

Comment: You probably meant data-requires. I don't think you can do that. Why not put them all together? data-requires='js/base/paths|js/base/dialog|js/base/notifier'

Comment: I think I'll stick with putting all of them together. The only reason for writing 3 requires was to make it look pretty for new devs joining the team.

Comment: Yep, it would be nice to be able to do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put them all in one if you separated them by something then split them up and put them in an Array.

```
var arrayData = document.getElementById('viewport').getAttribute('data-requries');
var arr = arrayData.split(',');

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/S7D2D/1/

Answer (score 20):

The answer to your question is that HTML does not support multiple instances of the same property.  All the typical ways that you might retrieve that attribute will only retrieve one of the three.

The usual way to solve this problem is to use a single instance of the attribute and put multiple paths as the value.  For paths, they are usually separated by semi-colons.

```
<div id="viewport" data-requires='js/base/paths;js/base/dialog;js/base/notifier'>
```

And, then use code to break up the multi-valued attribute into an array.

```
var requiredPaths = document.getElementById("viewport").getAttribute("data-requires").split(";");
```

Comment: This method works with Foundation dropdowns to allow multiple data-options like this: `data-options="is_hover:true; align: right"`. Thanks, as I could not find how to do this anywhere else.

Answer (score 10):

You can use more complex structures within `data-` attributes.

Instead of this:

```
<div id="viewport" 
data-requires='js/base/paths'
data-requires='js/base/dialog'
data-requires='js/base/notifier'>
```

you can do this:

```
<div id="viewport"
data-requires='["js/base/paths", "js/base/dialog", "js/base/notifier"]'>
</div>
```

Proof using `jQuery.data()` (which just retrieves the array this way: `jQuery('#viewport').data('requires')`) is here: http://jsfiddle.net/3StZs/

Comment: Curious if there are any browsers would choke on this…

Comment: @rohit_wason: Why are you worried about this? That technique is around for years now, and most likely even the derelict browsers are supported (although firstly, they should no longer be used, and secondly, jQuery version would need to support them). Any specific concern you have regarding that? jQuery seems to be pretty compatible with very old browsers, if yours is a lot older, you may need to use a lot older version of jQuery to support it.

Comment: My original comment was about truly using multiple attributes. I don't think I read the question thoroughly. I see now.