# is it possible to store multiple key/values inside 1 data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it is possible to store multiple key/values inside a `data-attr` like:

```
​<a href="#" data-social="network:facebook; socialId:123456789" id="facebook">Facebook</a>
```

and then when using them in my script just pick at them like `$('#facebook').data('social.socialId');` or something like that instead of having to break each of them up into their own attribute?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to restrict it either to only one `data-*` attribute. You can always use as many as you need.

```
​<a href="#" data-social-network="facebook" data-social-id="123456789" id="facebook">Facebook</a>
```

```
var socialId = $('#facebook').data('social-id');
```

---

But, if you still insist. It is possible to store a JSON string and parse it.

```
​<a href='#' data-social='{ "network": "facebook", "socialId": 123456789 }' id='facebook'>Facebook</a>
```

```
var socialId = $('#facebook').data('social').socialId;
```

The JSON Object is automatically parsed by jQuery.

Comment: This answer does not seem correct. This SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26341866/236306 and the one that follows https://stackoverflow.com/a/43859478/236306 both note that effectively, it is wrong to repeat an attribute in an HMTL5 tag. This SO Q&A however addresses how multiple items of data may be stored in the one data attribute https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962091/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-data-name-atributes-in-html5

Comment: @Alan, what's the *repeated* attribute? I can't see the relevance to your comment

Comment: I was referring to the code above:
`<a href="#" data-social-network="facebook" data-social-id="123456789" id="facebook">Fa...`
which has more than one HTML5 `data` attributes in one `a` tag. Apologies if I misread that and it was an example of what not to do maybe? (PS: New to commenting here - tried to politely prefix with @Alexander but clearly that's not allowed as editor keeps auto-stripping that on save).

Comment: @Alan, they are not the same

Comment: I apologize for my error @Alexander. I understood that per HTML element only one `data-` attribute was allowed. Clearly I was wrong and I now see [noted in the HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) "Every HTML element may have any number of custom data attributes specified, with any value". Thank you for your patience while I circled around and spotted your replies and finally understood. PS: SO i/f stops me switching my vote to an upvote; while there will be a good reason for that, it fails this use case : (

Answer (score 0):

you could store data in JSON format in the attribute like

```
<div id="myElement" data-json='["value1", "value2", "value3"]'></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

and then retrieve it like

```
var data = JSON.parse($('#myElement').attr('data-json')​);
```

Answer (score 0):

Store them as an object.

```
$('#facebook').data('social', { network: 'facebook', socialId: 12345679 });
```

Comment: wouldn't you just use `$('a').data('social', { network: 'facebook', socialId: 12345679 });`. As the jQuery 'data' element isn't an attribute that is rendered to the DOM. `data-` is only used to prevent collision with existing HTL attributes.

Comment: This adds this data element to **ALL** `a` tags in the DOM. That's not what's requested.

Comment: I know it wasn't what's requested @bartlaarhoven, just making a correction to an answer that was provided was all. :-P

Comment: @bartlaarhoven Good call when I posted this I missed that the OP had an id on the a tag, I updated the solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSON and that's automatically parsed, I believe

```
​<a href="#" data-social="{network:facebook; socialId:123456789}" id="facebook">Facebook</a>
```

Would make possibilities for

```
$('#facebook').data('social').socialId;
```

Comment: Nah you'll need to add some quotation marks indeed. :P You have a good answer already though so I'll just leave it at this.